# Как залить сайт на github что бы не пропадали картинки?

Tags: github

Такой вопрос уже 2 рой день мучаюсь , загружаю на сервер GITHAB сайт и не отображаются картинки! уже менял .png на .PNG и Букву делал заглавную! Ничего не работает!

Можете посмотреть ни на одном сайте не отображаются картинки!

https://github.com/pologenki/My-Projects/tree/master/My%20Project

https://pologenki.github.io/Test-4-/

Comment: Поставь относительный путь

Comment: А нормально что основ. страница 404 выдаёт? (https://pologenki.github.io/)